# compare an array and object to see if item exists

Tags: javascript

I have the following:
An array

```
const myArray = ['john', 'frank', 'paul'];
```

then I have an array of objects

```
const myObjectArray = [
    {name: 'nery', age: 34, present: true},
    {name: 'john', age: 15, present: false},
    etc
]
```

How can I check if myArray value is found in the myObjectArray?
I thought about looping through myArray and then in each iteration looping through myObjectArray to see if it is present.  However this seems so 2001.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `myArray.includes(name)`?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Are you trying produce true if any items in `myArray` match the `name` key for an object inside of `myObjectArray`? Please be specific and show your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check if an item from first array is in the name of second array use `some` to return a `boolean`

```js
const myArray = ["john", "frank", "paul"];

const myObjectArray = [
  { name: "nery", age: 34, present: true },
  { name: "john", age: 15, present: false },
];
res = myObjectArray.some((o) => myArray.includes(o.name));
console.log(res);
```

If you want to return the object that has same name from first array use `filter`

```js
const myArray = ["john", "frank", "paul"];

const myObjectArray = [
  { name: "nery", age: 34, present: true },
  { name: "john", age: 15, present: false },
];
res = myObjectArray.filter((o) => myArray.includes(o.name));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.prototype.some` and `Array.prototype.includes` functions.

```js
const names = ['john', 'frank', 'paul'];

const people = [
  {name: 'nery', age: 34, present: true},
  {name: 'john', age: 15, present: false},
];

const exists = people.some(({ name }) => names.includes(name));
console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.prototype.find can find the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```
const myArray = ["john", "frank", "paul"];

const myObjectArray = [
  { name: "nery", age: 34, present: true },
  { name: "john", age: 15, present: false },
];
res = myObjectArray.find((o) => myArray.includes(o.name));
console.log(res);
```